# How to give players a score on a ranking/prediction task?

Tags: algorithm

I have a website built with php/mysql, and I am looking for help in communicating to a Programmer what I want him to do with a Poll/Prediction game that I am trying to create.

For purposes of discussion, assume a game where perhaps 100 players try to predict the top 5 finishers in a Golf Tournament of perhaps 9 Golfers.

I am looking for help in how to create and assign a score based upon the accuracy of prediction.

The players provide a rank ordering using a drag and drop function to order the players from 1 through 5.  This ordering has already been coded, and the ranks are stored somehow in the DB (I do not know how).

My initial thinking is to ask the coder to create a script which will assign a score from 1 to 5 for each Golfer that the player nominated to be in the Top 5.

So, a player who predicted perfectly would be awarded a perfect score of 12345.
His first golfer received a 1 for finishing first, second a 2 for finishing second, third golfer receives a 3 for finishing third, and so on.

Anybody less than perfect would have a score higher than 12345.

Players who got the first four positions correct would have to be differentiated on the basis of the finish of their fifth Golfer.

So, one might score 12347 and the other 12348 and the player with the highest score (12348) would be the loser in a matchup of the two players.

A player who did poorly, might have a score of 53419.

Question:
Is this a viable way of creating a score which the players of my game can be ranked upon?

Is it possible to instead simply have something like a Spearman Rank-Order Correlation calculated comparing the Actual Finish Positions with the Predicted Finish Positions for each player,
and then rank players on the basis of the correlation coefficients for their rankings?

Thanks for any help in clarifying how to conceptualize this before approaching a programmer who gets annoyed when I don't really know what I want him to do ahead of time.

Comment: This sounds like [horse racing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parimutuel_wagering).

Comment: Yes, selecting the Super High Five in one race would be a reasonable analogy.  The earliest Picks in the Sequence are the most important.

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite interesting problem.
It seems that there are three components that need to be considered in the scoring: the number of correct predictions, the order of correct predictions, and the weight of correct predictions.

For example, assume the truth is: 
1,5,10,15,20

Here are some predictions:

1,6,7,8,9    : only predicted first one
2,1,10,21,30 : 1 and 10, but the order of 1 is incorrect
20,15,1,5,30 : hit four in the top 5, but the orders are incorrect

It depends on what you value most. You may first check how many in the top 5 the user has predicted, add a value, and then penalize wrong orders. The weight for each position should also be different, this way 
1,5,10,15,20 will rank higher than 1,5,10,20,15 and higher than 1,10,5,20,15

Spearman may be working, but I feel it could be too coarse for your purpose.

Comment: I am trying to assign prizes to the Top Predictors, so it is important to Rank Order them.

Comment: Thanks. In game, it is most important to get the First Place Finisher Correct, then next most important is to get the Second place finisher correct, and so forth.  The player's First Prediction must be most dominant.  If player's First Pick finishes 5th, then he must be ranked lower than all other players whose first pick finished between 1 and 4th place.... but he will be ranked higher than all players whose first pick was worse than 6th place. I converted the Tourney Placings for each player's Picks into ordinal sequence: 14253 - No digits go past 9. No Zero used.  Seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very similar problem that search engines have.  EG, in search engine evaluation, the actual outcomes are preferred results provided by humans, and the predicted outcomes are the results delivered by the search engine.  In both your task and for search engines, I'd guess you care a lot more about the accuracy of the winner than the accuracy of the 5th place finisher.  If that is the case, then the [mean average precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Mean_average_precision) is probably a good measure.

Comment: Thanks, Rob.  As indicated in another comment, Each Prediction is more important than others below it in the sequence.  It is something like calculating Payouts for Super Bets at the race track, the people who have the first few positions in the correct sequence are ranking higher for payout purposes. So, anybody with 1st and 2nd place correct have to be ranked higher than anybody, and then move on down the sequence.   So, a player with only the winner correct: 1-6-5-4-3 will rank higher than somebody with a 2-3-4-5-1 outcome.